# Referencing different types of cells-(ie. strings, doubles)-multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

First off, go easy I'm a novice.  I need to reference different types of cells (ie. strings, doubles) from a template workbook that I create and save as multiple workbooks.  I have figured out how to get the value or string to transfer to my master file but I want to be able to open one of the workbooks and change a value and hence have the master file change too.  Also, the master workbook is saved in a different location than the other workbooks.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub HyperLink()

   'This macro creates a new excel workbook based on the selected part number of the master file.
   'It also fills in three cells in the newly created excel file based on the master.
   'Certain cells in the newly created workbook are referenced back to the master
   'Finally the part number in the master excel is hyperlinked to the newly created excel

    Dim PartNumber As String
    Dim EAU As Integer
    Dim CurrentMaterial As Double
    Dim SimForging As String
    Dim EstForging As String
    Dim ProcessSavings As String

    ColumnLocation = ActiveCell.Column
    CellLocation = ActiveCell.Address

    PartNumber = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column) 'Defines the part number for the active cell
    EAU = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value  'Defines the EAU for the selected part number (column C)
    CurrentMaterial = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'Defines the Mat. Cost for the selected part number (column D)

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    If IsNull(PartNumber) = False Then
        Workbooks.Add
        FilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\" & PartNumber & ".xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\Template.xls"
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = PartNumber
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = EAU
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = CCur(CurrentMaterial)

        'I dont know what to use here?????????????????????
        SimForging = Range("A8").FormulaR1C1
        ProcessSavings = Range("C11").FormulaR1C1
        EstForging = Range("F2").FormulaR1C1

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close
        ActiveWindow.Close

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="Pricing\" & PartNumber & ".xlsx", TextToDisplay:=PartNumber

        'Again I don't know what to do here in order to make it dynamic????????????
        'I want to be able to change the EstForging in PartNumber.xlsx and have it update the master file
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = EstForging
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = SimForging
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = ProcessSavings

        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .Calculation = CalcMode
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Siddarth,

Thanks for the response, it should work like this.

Choose the cell (a PartNumber ie. 1234) I want to run the macro for and start macro

1) Define PartNumber, EAU and CurrentMaterial
      PartNumber = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column) 
      EAU = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
      CurrentMaterial = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

2) Open a template I created.
     Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\New Parts - Miller, Crum\Forging Justification\Template.xls"

3) Save the Template.xls as a new file (ie. 1234.xlsx)
     "C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\" & PartNumber & ".xlsx"

4) Place the PartNumber, EAU and CurrentMaterial into the 1234.xlsx
      Range("A2").Select
      ActiveCell.Value = PartNumber
      ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = EAU
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = CCur(CurrentMaterial)

5) Define SimForging, EstForging and ProcessSavings in the 1234.xlsx
      SimForging = ActiveCell.Offset( , )
      EstForging = ActiveCell.Offset( , )
      ProcessSavings = ActiveCell.Offset( , )

6) Save 1234.xlsx and close it.

7) With the master file active again, place Simforging,EstForging and ProcessSavings in the same row as the PartNumber
      ActiveCell.Offset( , ) = SimForging
      ActiveCell.Offset( , ) = EstForging
      ActiveCell.Offset( , ) = ProcessSavings

8) Add a hyperlink to the PartNumber cell to the file I just created (1234.xlsx)
   ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="Pricing\" & PartNumber & ".xlsx",_ TextToDisplay:=PartNumber

9) Save the master workbook and stop macro.

I then want to be able to hit the hyperlink and open 1234.xlsx.
Then change the ProcessSavings inside of 1234.xlsx, save and close it.
I want to be able to see the changes in the master workbook.

Right now I have only been able to bring the values across from 1234.xlsx but when I change them, it does not update in the master file????  EstForging and ProcessSavings are doubles while
SimForging is a string.

Comment: Could you please clarify point 5? Where are you trying to retrieve the values from?

Comment: I am trying to reference cells from the newly created excel (ie. 1234.xlsx) back to the master workbook.  So inside the master workbook, I would do something like this              ActiveCell.Offset(0,23) = "='C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\[1234.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$11"

Comment: So are you trying to store that formula in SimForging?

Answer (score 0):

> > > > ```
> > > >    'I dont know what to use here?????????????????????
> > > >     SimForging = Range("A8").FormulaR1C1
> > > >     ProcessSavings = Range("C11").FormulaR1C1
> > > >     EstForging = Range("F2").FormulaR1C1
> > > > ```

Is this what you are trying?

```
    'I dont know what to use here?????????????????????
    SimForging = Range("A8").Value
    ProcessSavings = Range("C11").Value
    EstForging = Range("F2").Value
```

I am kind of confused with your requirements. Can you put it pointwise how the macro is supposed to behave. What I mean is specify what steps macro is supposed to take. Use filenames and cell addresses in your explanation. See this for example

1) Start Macro

2) Get PartNumber, EAU, CurrentMaterial from active cell in current workbook

3) Decide on a file name using

`"C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\" & PartNumber & ".xlsx"`

4) Open the master file `"C:\Documents and Settings\Brandon's\Desktop\Forging Justification\Template.xls"`

And so on...

Once we understand what you exactly want, the we will be able to help you in a much better way. :)

Sid

Comment: Yes, I tried ProcessSavings = Range("C11").Value but it wont update

Comment: @user1251120: Please see the comment that I posted in your question.